# Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu Desktop 13.10 dual boot problem

Tags: easybcd

I installed Ubuntu after Windows 8.1 on different partitions. 
Then I installed EasyBSD. I added an Ubuntu partitions entry. Then I selected "grub2"
but Ubuntu can not open, the computer just waits.

I reset then tried to load Ubuntu but Windows8.1 boot manager not grub2 comes up.

My boot repair program report link:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6589104/

Answer (score 0):

If you installed EasyBCD and make an entry for Ubuntu,then the windows bootloader will be shown on the startup not grub.

If you want the grub to list the os's on startup,then [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is the only option.